# Problems with PHP explode

Tags: php, drupal, token, explode

I'm using this code:

```
$imageurl = "http://siteadress/sites/default/files/bjorn_4.jpg";
$pieces = explode('/', $imageurl);
print_r($pieces);
```

to split up an url.

The print_r gives me this result =

```
Array ( [0] => http://siteadress/sites/default/files/bjorn_4.jpg )
```

Shouldn't it split up the URL after each /? So it will be Array ( [0] => http:/ [1] => / [2] => siteadresses or something like that?

Comment: Looks to me like you're just splitting the string `"[node:field_banner_image]"`, which has no `/`... Am I missing something?

Comment: No deceze, the [node:field_banner_image] is replaced by the link when the code is readed, so it tries to split up the Url, not the [node:field_banner_image] :)

Comment: OK, if you say so, I have no knowledge of Drupal...

Comment: And where is that `"[node:field_banner_image]"` replaced with URL? In the code snippet you posted - there's no replacement occurring.

Comment: In drupal, you can use something called Tokens. This is "aliases" for fields in the database, so instead of defining the page id, the field name, etc. etc. you write that short line and the site outputs the link.

Comment: cant u store the value in a variable and then explode

Comment: You don't understand.. in the **code** you posted, there is no replacement occurring. It's **impossible** to have a replacement occur unless you call a function of some sort that does the replacement. That's why you are not exploding the URL, you are exploding a string that says `"[node:field_banner_image]"`.

Comment: I think you should try to find out how /when the replacement occurs. There's nothing wrong with the explode mechanism you have in place.

Comment: N.B, the replacement is occuring on the site i'm working on. Not here. 

Lee Davis: The replacement occurs instantly when the page loads. It's replaced before I run the explode on it.

Comment: Why do you post a code that's not the code you actually use? In the snippet posted, there's clearly a string being exploded that hasn't got a slash character in it and you wonder why it doesn't work. There's nothing wrong with `explode` function, this is a classic PICNIC / ID ten T "problem".

Comment: Are you satisfied now N.B? That is the exactly same code as before, cause the [node:field_banner_image] gets replaced with that URL before the explode function starts..

Comment: @DanielLundahl - I copypasted and ran the code you added in the edited post, and I get an array with 7 elements, just as expected..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try :

```
$imageurl = [node:field_banner_image];
```

Because with the quotes explode will think that the string is [node:field_banner_image] and not the string inside.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear. The [node:field_banner_image] is like a variable containing the link. So I can't change the content of the [node:field_banner_image] cause it's set by drupal.

Comment: The new code doesn't work either. With that, it doesn't output anything so I believe some errors occur in the background. :/
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Well I think I can't help you more and beside I don't know very much Drupal so... Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

like Edouard Moinard   said

```
           $imageurl = [node:field_banner_image];
           $pieces = explode('/', $imageurl);
           print_r($pieces);
```

this should work

Comment: Nope, drupal doesn't like that I think cause all output disappears :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your `Array[0]` element to any variable and split that variable like:

```
  $image=Array[0];
  $pieces = explode('/', $image);
  print_r($pieces);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with Drupal but a quick read of the documentation gave me this:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/8

> `token_replace()`
>
> Replaces all tokens in a given string with appropriate values.

Hopefully that helps

Comment: Hmm, this didn't work either :/ I'll try some different "versions" of that code.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving a try

Check the view source of the page, check if you are getting %2F or "/"

Secondly, check with explode('/', << the field value >>)